# Preencher Array com variaveis recebidas via POST

Tags: php

Preciso montar um array igual o abaixo:

```
$aDup = array(
    array('carlos','2016-06-20','300.00'),
    array('mario','2016-07-20','300.00'),
    array('joao','2016-08-20','300.00'),
    array('silvio','2016-09-20','300.00')
);
```

Para preencher abaixo assim:

```
foreach ($aDup as $dup) {
    $nDup = $dup[0];
    $dVenc = $dup[1];
    $vDup = $dup[2];
    $resp = $nfe->tagdup($nDup, $dVenc, $vDup);
}
```

Recebendo esses dados via POST

```
$nDup = $_POST['nDup'];
$dVenc = $_POST['nDup'];
$vDup = $_POST['nDup'];
```

Enviados por este HTML que esta assim:

```
<input name='nDup[]' type='text'>
<input name='dVenc[]' type='text'>
<input name='vDup[]' type='text'>
```

Comment: Porque colocou `[ ]` no atributo input name?

Comment: Pois ele é um array e pode ser repetido esses INPUTS, exemplo, pode ter mais que 1 ou 2 inputs com name nDup, dVenc, vDup

Comment: Qual é a questão mesmo ? Qual a dificuldade que está a encontrar ?

Comment: no caso você que criar uma array dentro de outra array correto ?

Comment: já tentou assim => `<input name="nDup[duplicata][ ]">`?

Comment: Pessoal, se puderem prestar atenção na pergunta, separei o que preciso fazer, assim, tenho inputs que podem ser repetido 1 ou mais vezes, dependendo o numero de duplicatas, com name='nDup[]' dVenc[] e vDup[], estou recebendo eles via POST, e preciso criar um array com esses POSTS igual a este $aDup = array(
     array('mario','2016-07-20','300.00'),
    array('joao','2016-08-20','300.00')
    ); 
SENDO que o mario é nDup, a data ao lado é dVenc e o valor é vDup

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que os inputs sejam repetidos o mesmo numero de vezes você pode fazer assim:
html:

```
<form method="POST">
<div>
<input name='nDup[]' type='text'>
<input name='nDup[]' type='text'>
<input name='nDup[]' type='text'>
</div>
<div>
<input name='dVenc[]' type='text'>
<input name='dVenc[]' type='text'>
<input name='dVenc[]' type='text'>
</div>
<div>
<input name='vDup[]' type='text'>
<input name='vDup[]' type='text'>
<input name='vDup[]' type='text'>
</div>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

php:

```
    <?php
$dados = [];

//supondo que os arrays $_POST nDup, dVenc e vDup tem tamanhos iguais
for($i=0;$i < count($_POST['nDup']);$i++){
    $dados[] = [
    isset($_POST['nDup'][$i]) ? $_POST['nDup'][$i] : null,
    isset($_POST['dVenc'][$i]) ? $_POST['dVenc'][$i] : null, 
    isset($_POST['vDup'][$i]) ? $_POST['vDup'][$i] : null];
}
var_dump($dados);
```

Produzindo o seguinte resultado:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'maria' (length=5)
      1 => string '2016-06-20' (length=10)
      2 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'joão' (length=5)
      1 => string '2016-06-20' (length=10)
      2 => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'ana' (length=3)
      1 => string '2016-06-25' (length=10)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
```